# Non-OK-status: GpuLaunchKernel(...) status: Internal: invalid configuration argument

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I'm on windows and trying to get Pycharm to use my GPU to speed up my CNN.

I'm running python 3.8, cuda_11.2

As you can see, all the .dll's load successfully (They're in System32, it couldn't find any of them in  the cuda directory)

```
2021-03-22 14:52:25.794812: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default

/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
Found 10270 images belonging to 1 classes.
Found 15009 images belonging to 1 classes.
2021-03-22 14:52:33.362104: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_cpu_device.cc:41] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2021-03-22 14:52:33.364947: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2021-03-22 14:52:33.397364: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce GTX 1050 Ti with Max-Q Design computeCapability: 6.1
coreClock: 1.2905GHz coreCount: 6 deviceMemorySize: 4.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 104.43GiB/s
2021-03-22 14:52:33.397809: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
2021-03-22 14:52:33.410127: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_11.dll
2021-03-22 14:52:33.410341: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublasLt64_11.dll
2021-03-22 14:52:33.416656: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2021-03-22 14:52:33.419889: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2021-03-22 14:52:33.428505: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2021-03-22 14:52:33.434403: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_11.dll
2021-03-22 14:52:33.436549: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_8.dll
2021-03-22 14:52:33.436834: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1862] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-03-22 14:52:33.437505: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2021-03-22 14:52:33.438954: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce GTX 1050 Ti with Max-Q Design computeCapability: 6.1
coreClock: 1.2905GHz coreCount: 6 deviceMemorySize: 4.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 104.43GiB/s
2021-03-22 14:52:33.439493: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
2021-03-22 14:52:33.439726: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_11.dll
2021-03-22 14:52:33.439946: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublasLt64_11.dll
2021-03-22 14:52:33.440192: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2021-03-22 14:52:33.440393: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2021-03-22 14:52:33.440601: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2021-03-22 14:52:33.440799: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_11.dll
2021-03-22 14:52:33.440998: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_8.dll
2021-03-22 14:52:33.441241: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1862] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-03-22 14:52:34.415439: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1261] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2021-03-22 14:52:34.415660: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1267]      0 
2021-03-22 14:52:34.415781: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1280] 0:   N 
2021-03-22 14:52:34.416117: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1406] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 2982 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1050 Ti with Max-Q Design, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2021-03-22 14:52:34.417493: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_gpu_device.cc:99] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2021-03-22 14:52:34.636484: F .\tensorflow/core/kernels/random_op_gpu.h:246] Non-OK-status: GpuLaunchKernel(FillPhiloxRandomKernelLaunch<Distribution>, num_blocks, block_size, 0, d.stream(), key, counter, gen, data, size, dist) status: Internal: invalid configuration argument
```

Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)

I'm very stumped on this. tensorflow-gpu and tensorflow install fine and my CNN that I'm testing is very basic as I just to get this GPU to work.

After soon googleing I'm aware that if the batch size isn't divisable by the batch_size without leaving remainers, this error can occur. But I'm pretty sure with my code, it should work.

Here's the code:

```
# keras imports for the dataset and building our neural network
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Conv2D, MaxPool2D, Flatten
from keras.utils import np_utils


# to calculate accuracy
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

# loading the dataset
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

# building the input vector from the 28x28 pixels
X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)
X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
X_test = X_test.astype('float32')

# normalizing the data to help with the training
X_train /= 255
X_test /= 255

# one-hot encoding using keras' numpy-related utilities
n_classes = 10
print("Shape before one-hot encoding: ", y_train.shape)
Y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, n_classes)
Y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, n_classes)
print("Shape after one-hot encoding: ", Y_train.shape)

# building a linear stack of layers with the sequential model
model = Sequential()
# convolutional layer
model.add(Conv2D(25, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='valid', activation='relu', input_shape=(28,28,1)))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(1,1)))
# flatten output of conv
model.add(Flatten())
# hidden layer
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
# output layer
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

# compiling the sequential model
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'], optimizer='adam')

# training the model for 10 epochs
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=128, epochs=10, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test))
```

Comment: An internal error in Tensorflow doesn't constitute a on-topic CUDA programming related question. I have now removed the CUDA tag twice. Please don't make me have to remove it again. Also, don't post error text as images. They can't be searched for and are completely unhelpful to future visitors

Comment: @talonmies my apologies, I thought I forgot to include it as there was no message it was removed by someone else.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68054463/14337775